# How to get a specific cell in a TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This is my table view so far: click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttdFa.jpg)

As you can see I have 4 items in my TableView. I have loaded them with a Core Data array. In my Core data entity I have an attribute called "Paid" set to BOOLEAN default value of "NO". My table view links up to a DetailViewController Page in which there is a button called "Paid". When the user clicks this button, that particular item gets marked "PAID". So In my cellForRowAtIndexPath I check to see if the item is paid or not. By the picture shows my code must be wrong here, because only one item is being marked paid. However when I NSLog the other items in the table view they are marked "Paid" too. Here is the code for my cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];        

NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"OwedMoney"];
YouOweArray = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
OwedMoney *YouOweObject = [YouOweArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (YouOweObject.paid.boolValue == NO)

{

    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}

else if (YouOweObject.paid.boolValue == YES)
{

    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    [cell  setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
}
```

In my DetailViewController I have a "Paid" button with the following code:

```
 - (IBAction)paid:(id)sender {

     //Fetch Entity

     NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
     NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"OwedMoney"];

     //Create an array that stores the contents of that entity

     youOweArray = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

     //Create managedObjectId

     NSManagedObject *YouOweData  = [youOweArray objectAtIndex:0];
     NSManagedObjectID *moID = [YouOweData objectID];

     //Successfully got the managedObjectId

     NSLog(@"This is the id %@", moID);

     BOOL Found =  NO;
     OwedMoney *Object;


     for (OwedMoney *OwedObject in youOweArray)
     {
         NSManagedObjectID *OwedId = [OwedObject objectID];

         NSLog(@"%@", OwedObject);
         if (OwedId == moID)
         {
             Found = YES;
             Object = OwedObject;
             break;
         }

     }

     if (Found)
     {

         BOOL isPaid = Found;
         Object.paid = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isPaid];

         NSLog(@"Is it paid: %@",Object.paid.boolValue? @"Yes":@"No");

         NSError *error = nil;
         [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
     }
 }
```

Comment: a NSNumber most likely

Comment: I updated the code. What could possible be the error if only my First cell is responding the code correctly but not the other cells?

Comment: show us how you mark something .. the code that does it

Comment: Well the code that determines if it's paid or not is in my if statement. Unless you want to know the code that's inside my paid button when a user taps the "Paid" button?

Comment: yes.. I would like that

Comment: NSManagedObject *YouOweData  = [youOweArray objectAtIndex:0];
this line may make the problem as its taking always 0th index

Answer (score 0):

Take a reference of selected object from your main controller and put that in your line :

```
NSManagedObject *YouOweData  = [youOweArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

and replace it as ;

```
NSManagedObject *YouOweData  = [youOweArray objectAtIndex:i];
```

To check the selected row in your mainController, you have to make a property in DetailViewController:

```
@property (nonatomic) int selectedIndex;
```

In MainController, you have to set the property value in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Suppose detailController is the object of DetailViewController.

Set as :

```
detailController.selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
```

In detailViewController :

```
NSManagedObject *YouOweData  = [youOweArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];
```

Comment: so i is this: NSIndexPath *i = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

Comment: But this is in my DetailViewController. How do I get the selected object of my TableViewController in my DetailViewController?

Comment: For instance I can do NSIndexPath *i = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] But in my DetailViewController I don't have access to my tableView. I can't even do [youOweArray ObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];